# Showing author page if user has no post

Tags: posts, comments, author, author-template

I have a page with profiles in which people can post or `comment` on a `post`. The problem is that if this user chooses to comment instead of post, he or she will not get an `author page` until it has submitted a post. Is there a way to show the author page anyway? Because I have a function that shows the comments on the author page, but because it has no posts in it, that won't show too...

I hope someone can help me out.

PS: I already tried several plugins, but those things didn't work out.

FYI: this is default behavior of Wordpress and I am using the default `author.php` template which has an "`if have posts`" loop, if not, `loop-no-posts` loop. So the author page is not created is there is no post. That is the whole point.

Edit: my code:

```
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

            <ul><?php
    global $wpdb;
    $user_id = $post->post_author;  
    $where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id = ' . $user_id ;

    $user = get_userdata($user_id);

    ?>

   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php responsive_entry_before(); ?>
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>       

                <div class="post-entry"><blockquote>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >

                        </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

            </article>    
            <?php responsive_entry_after(); ?>

        <?php 
        endwhile; 

        /* get_template_part( 'loop-nav' ); */

    else : 

        get_template_part( 'loop-no-posts' ); 

    endif; 
    ?>  


<?php
    $args = array(
        'user_id' => $user->ID,
        'number' => 10, // how many comments to retrieve
        'status' => 'approve'
        );

    $comments = get_comments( $args );

    if ( $comments )
    {
        foreach ( $comments as $c )
        {
        $output.= '<a href="'.get_comment_link().'">';
        $output.= get_the_title();
        $output.= '</a>';
        }

        echo $output;
    } else { echo "bla";}?>

</div>
```

Comment: It is really hard to say without seeing what code you are already using, and whether this is a theme your making on your own, or one that is already out there etc etc. Please try and describe your question with more detail, it would be hard to advise you without further details.

Comment: Well, I don't see what makes is hard, because this is `default behaviour of Wordpress`. I just want to know if it is possible to show an user author page (seeing it created) if there is no post and if so, how..

I am just using the default `author.php` of Wordpress. So the one with "if has posts" then a loop, else `loop-no-posts`.

Comment: So your saying that, if a user has no posts, then wordpress does not produce a yoursite.com/authorname page for that user. I was not aware of that behavior. Btw there is no default author.php page for wordpress, that file is created by the author of the theme, there could be any code in that file. The author.php file may be similar but  will differ from theme to theme. Hence my original comment.

Comment: If the author.php page is missing, wordpress then falls back to the index.php file to populate the author page, this behavior applies to many other templates files aswell with index.php being the fallback.

Comment: Jep, that's exactly what Wordpress does (or does not). It does not create the author page. Frankly, if someone has commented, but did not posted, the link to the author page is an ID instead of the username. If the same person submits the post, the link will change to the author's username...

And yes, sorry, there is no default author page in twentyeleven or ten. I made it myself, but that's no hocus pocus. Just "if have post" and an else...

Can I use a different function instead of `if_have_posts` that will show me the author page?

Comment: You may need to change you permalink structure to be the post-title instead of post id. Done in apperance > permalink. And to solve your overall problem you will need to create a "custom" author.php, if you are using twentytwelve or twentyeleven, since they are not included.

Comment: Don't you mean that the page is created but that there are no posts on it? I just checked and I do get an author archive-- an empty one-- if the author has not posted anything. However, it is still not clear what you are doing. Post the code for the page that handles this: "I have a page with profiles in which people can post or comment on a post"

Comment: When creating your author.php, this will probably be of use: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41078/show-author-archive-pages-for-authors-with-no-posts?rq=1

Comment: @ Ronburgundy Did try that already, did not work... It has nothing to do with the permalink btw.

@s_ha_dum no, the page is not created because it redirects me to author=56 instead of /author/authorname... which is the correct one, because the ones with posts are being redirected to the last one.

Comment: ^^ Assuming that 'authorname' is user ID = 65 then that is is the _same_ page. You are describing a permalinks problem whether you think so or not.

Comment: But why on earth I am getting this "permalink error" on only people who have no posts? 

PS: I have posted my snippet for you @s_ha_dum

Comment: Have you tried the information listed under setting author information on this page? http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

Comment: Btw, your code above reads: IF THERE ARE POSTS -> THEN GET THE AUTHOR. So your template is saying, if there are no posts, which is the case when they have only commented, then get loop-no-posts template part. Which is one reason why you cannot display any author information, because you have no author...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
        $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author)); 
        ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) ?>
        <h2>Posts by <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?>:</h2>
            <ul>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?></a>,
                    <?php the_time('d M Y'); ?> in <?php the_category('&');?>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <p><?php _e('No posts by this author.'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'user_id' => $curauth->ID,
            'number' => 10, // how many comments to retrieve
            'status' => 'approve'
            );

        $comments = get_comments( $args );

        if ( $comments )
        {
            $output.= "<ul>";
            foreach ( $comments as $c )
            {
            $output.= '<li>';
            $output.= '<a href="'.get_comment_link( $c->comment_ID ).'">';
            $output.= get_the_title($c->comment_post_ID);
            $output.= '</a>';
            $output.= "</li>\n";
            }
            $output.= '</ul>';

            echo $output;
        } else { 
            echo "bla";
        }
?>
```

Modified from [here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates)

Edit: Added OP's code

Comment: Thanks Ron, but it does not do what I want. I already can show the posts if they exist and show anything I like if I don't have them, but the problem is that if there is no post, the COMMENTS the user has made are not shown too...

I updated my code to show you how I have implemented the comments... so now, if there is no post, then no comment will shown. If there is a post, all comments the user has made will shown too... That is not what I want.

Comment: not to be blunt but your making some basic mistakes, ones I explained above in a previous comment. In the snippet you updated above your logic works like so: IF POSTS -> GET USER, THEN GET POSTS. IF NO POSTS -> GET COMMENTS FROM USER. You cannot get the comments using `$user->user_id`, when you haven't even set `$user` because `$user` is inside of `if has posts`...

Comment: i update my answer to include your comments output that will display under the posts regardless if there are any posts or not.

Comment: excellent im happy it worked, cheers!