# How to make custom user profile page public?

Tags: users, profiles

My website users can view their profiles and edit their profiles on a front-end custom page (/user/). How can I make the profile pages public?

Page slug for user profile page is `/user/` and profile edit page is `/user/edit/`. I want to make the profile page public, public profile page slug can be `/user/UserName/`.

Can anyone help me to achieve this? Please.

Comment: How are you implementing this front end profile editing behaviour? WordPress itself does not have that functionality.

Comment: Editing behavior comes from a plugin actually, but profile page by myself.

Comment: by users you mean default wordpress users? usually wordpress populates all these as author pages. you could change the url from author to user via permalink_rewrite and you would need to create/style a author.php template file. correct..? and since i guess, that your users will not create posts, you would need something like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41078/show-author-archive-pages-for-authors-with-no-posts)